# timer_create says invalid argument in solaris 10?

Tags: c, timer, time.h

I've a piece of code that sets a timer, its working in most of the os very fine except in solaris 10, here it is not able to schedule the function and failing to set timer_create with errno 22(EINVAL), I'm having no clue why this issue is happening , I tried checking the variable CLOCK_REALTIME, but of no use..my code as follows:

```
void set_timer(timer_t  *timer_id, float delay, float interval, 
               timer_callback  func, int val)
{
    int status =0;
    struct itimerspec ts;
    struct sigevent se;

    se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    se.sigev_value.sival_int = val;
    se.sigev_notify_function = func;
    se.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

    status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se, timer_id);

    ts.it_value.tv_sec = abs(delay);
    ts.it_value.tv_nsec = (delay-abs(delay)) * 1e09;
    ts.it_interval.tv_sec = abs(interval);
    ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = (interval-abs(interval)) * 1e09;

    status = timer_settime(*timer_id, 0, &ts, 0);
}
```

Comment: What does the manual page have to say?  The one for Solaris, not the POSIX definition?

Comment: Inside the virtualbox source code [ thanks google! ]:

`#ifndef RT_OS_SOLARIS /* Solaris 10 doesn't have SIGEV_THREAD */`

Comment: Thank you mevets, is  there anyway to make my code work in solaris 10??