# Why timer_create throw error for SIGEV_THREAD in solaris 10?

Tags: c++, c, timer, signals, solaris-10

I wrote a piece of by using timer_create for sets the timer to invoke a thread in which i set sigev_notify as SIGEV_THREAD, it is giving me error EINVAL(Invalid argument) but when i am setting sigev_notify as SIGEV_SIGNAL code is working fine.

my this piece of code is working in all OS even in solaris 11 but for solaris 10 giving me error.

code given below:

```
{
int status =0;
struct itimerspec ts;
struct sigevent se;

se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
se.sigev_value.sival_int = val;
se.sigev_notify_function = func;
se.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se, timer_id);

ts.it_value.tv_sec = abs(delay);
ts.it_value.tv_nsec = (delay-abs(delay)) * 1e09;
ts.it_interval.tv_sec = abs(interval);
ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = (interval-abs(interval)) * 1e09;

status = timer_settime(*timer_id, 0, &ts, 0);
```

}

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: For your reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5171/timer-create-3rt.html

Comment: timer_id is a variable which i defined like this (timer_t  *timer_id)

Comment: Where does it point to, before you pass it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47941299/694576 if not a duplicate to.

Comment: this is not pointing to anywhere i am declaring it like this
timer_t  timerPostDeviceUpdate_id;

Comment: ya that one( stackoverflow.com/q/47941299/694576) is also mine

i want to get rid of this issue..
solaris 10 only returning EINVAL for timer_create
i also checked code of timer.c to find out my mistake but i didn't get anything
link of timer.c (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/pthread/timer_create.c.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per [this man-page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5173/signal.h-3head.html) Solaris 10 does not know `SIGEV_THREAD`, but only

> The `sigev_notify` member specifies the notification mechanism to use when an asynchronous event occurs. The sigev_notify member may be defined with the following values:
>
> **`SIGEV_NONE`**
>
> No asynchronous notification is delivered when the event of interest occurs.
>
> **`SIGEV_SIGNAL`**
>
> A queued signal, with its value application-defined, is generated when the event of interest occurs.
>
> **`SIGEV_PORT`**
>
> An asynchronous notification is delivered to an event port when the event of interest occurs. The `sival_ptr` member points to a `port_notify_t` structure (see `port_associate(3C)`). The event port identifier as well as an application-defined cookie are part of the `port_notify_t` structure

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, according to my requirement i want to invoke a funtion at particular time period, i don't know much about SIGEV_PORT so can i use this, if yes then please guide me.

Comment: Solaris 11 seem to support `SIGEV_THREAD`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54772/signal.h-3head.html#scrolltoc

Comment: In solaris 11 my code is working fine. But my doubt is that timer.h and signal.h are defined under glibc then why arent they supported in solaris 10 but in solairs 11. I printed SIGEV_THREAD macro and its giving the value to be 3 in solaris 10.

Comment: @ram: Headers are just sugar.  If the library implementing the cake does  not handle it, there  is no way to convince it to do so.

Comment: Is there some other way to schedule my funtions in solaris 10??